# Primefaces selectOneButton: set selected option via JS/jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, client-side

Is it possible to change the selected item of a JSF selectOneButton component on the client side? Does Primefaces already ship a convenient method to do this?

When setting the 'widgetVar' attribute on the component, the corresponding JS object has a method 'select(a)' which seems to deactivate previously activated buttons, then activates the new button given by the parameter 'a':

```
select: function(a)
{
    this.buttons.filter(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active ui-state-hover").children(":radio").removeAttr("checked");
    a.addClass("ui-state-active").children(":radio").attr("checked", "checked").change()
}
```

But I don't know what to set as the parameter 'a'. Is this the right way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the jQuery object representing the concrete `<div>` which represents the desired button in the UI. They are all available by the `buttons` property of the widget var, which returns an array.

So, if you need to select the 3rd button, then this example should do it, provided a widget var name of `foo`:

```
foo.select($(foo.buttons[2]));
```

Note that this seems to be an internal method (which isn't hidden away using module pattern) and not documented in the Users Guide, so it's subject to undocumented changes in future PF versions.

Comment: Finally... first answer from the master himself :)
I was wondering why I always got a TypeError (Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'addClass'). I did not know that I have to use the $ function around the button. Can't wait for my ordered jquery book arriving tomorrow. Thank you BalusC, I really enjoy reading all of your answers and learning a lot of details of the JSF concepts.

Comment: You're welcome. The `addClass()` is indeed only available on a jQuery object, not on a plain HTML DOM element.